cant delete or create any logical partitions. HELP
I tried  fastboot delete-logical-partition product_a
(remote: 'Failed to write partition table')
and thats because i don't have a product_a partition.
Fastboot erase product_a
Erasing 'product_a'
FAILED (remote: 'Partition doesn't exist')

but then if i try creating a logical partition
fastboot create-logical-partition product_a 1
Creating 'product_a'
FAILED (remote: 'Partition already exists')

like i said its the same on all other partitions = system,odm,...
what am i doing wrong?
The phone i am trying to repair:
OnePlus Nord CE 3 Lite 5G CPH2467
(i got the system and all other images from the oxygen updater app)
